# Initialize "empty" DefaultTableModel with column names and column classes

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt, defaulttablemodel

I created my own class called `CustomTableModel` which extends from DefaultTableModel.

```
public class CustomTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {/*[...]*/}
```

My plan is that when you call my constructor with `new CustomTableModel();` you get a new `CustomTableModel` pre initialized with column names and column classes.

I got something like this running but the current implementation was something that once came out of the Eclipse AWT (Window Builder) where you can also use a GUI to setup your TableModel. The current implementation looks like this:

```
public static DefaultTableModel createEmptyModel() {
        model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][]{},
                new String[]{"Lfd. Nr.", "FB Nr.", "Auftr. / Meld. Nr.", "Betra Nr.", "Datum", "Bahnhof", "Str. Km.",
                        "Sprz.", "Arb. Zeit", "Mitarbeiter", "Auftrag / Objekt(e)", "Anmerkungen", "Fertig"}) {

            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Class[] columnTypes = new Class[]{Integer.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class,
                    String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, Boolean.class};

            @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return columnTypes[columnIndex];
            }
        };
        return model;
    }
```

As it might work it is not really a `CustomTableModel` at all, it's simply a `DefaultTableModel` created from within a method and returned + completely obfuscated (to me at least :) ).

While it works I am not sure how it exactly works, to my understanding it passes an empty array of objects (2D) as well as a String array to the constructor of the DefaultTableModel, which so far is understandable (Empty data + Column names) as required from the constructor of the DefaultTableModel. **But** I don't understand how the column classes are passed to the constructor after `..."Fertig"}) {` as both needed arguments (data + column names) have already been passed over.

My best guess was this approach:

```
   public CustomTableModel() {
        super(new Object[][]{{},{Integer.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class,
                String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, String.class, Boolean.class}}, new String[]{"Lfd. Nr.", "FB Nr.", "Auftr. / Meld. Nr.", "Betra Nr.", "Datum", "Bahnhof", "Str. Km.",
                "Sprz.", "Arb. Zeit", "Mitarbeiter", "Auftrag / Objekt(e)", "Anmerkungen", "Fertig"});
    }
```

Unfortunately this ends in a mess like this:
[image: Wrong outcome, Classes are not passed over right]

From this I assume that my pass of the classes is completely wrong.

What I expect to get is this (after adding rows):
[image: Result with "old" implementation from Eclipse AWT]

If someone could enlighten me on how to do this I would be really happy, I want to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at [`TableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html), it has two methods, `getColumnName` and `getColumnClass`, now, you've overrriden `getColumnClass`, which is fine, but internally to `DefaultTableModel`, it uses the column names you supplied to the constructor and returns them when `getColumnName` get's called.

This array also defines the return value for `getColumnCount`.

So, when `JTable#setModel` is called, one of things it will do (by default) is call it's `createDefaultColumnsFromModel` method, this then uses the `TableModel` to build it's `TableColumnModel`, using the `TableModel#getColumnName` method to provide the `TableColumn`'s `headerValue` property.

Magic!

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't understand how the column classes are passed to the constructor after ..."Fertig"}) { as both needed arguments (data + column names) have already been passed over.

They aren't passed to the constructor but initialized in the anonymous class.

The code you posted at the end also looks somewhat odd and probably wouldn't quite work as intended.

I'd probably not extend `DefaultTableModel` since it might require a lot of methods to be overwritten anyways but instead extend `AbstractTableModel` and implement the missing methods along with those that need to be overwritten (shouldn't be many).

Then I'd probably pass an array (you could use vargs here) or collection of `ColumnDefinition` (or some other name) objects that contain the name and the class, e.g. something like this:

```
TableModel tm = new CustomTableModel( new ColumnDefinition("Lfd. Nr.", Integer.class), 
                                      new ColumnDefinition("FB Nr.", String.class), ...)
```

The constructor would look like this:

```
public CustomTableModel(ColumnDefinition... columns) { ... }
```

Comment: `public CustomTableModel(ColumnDefinition... columns) { ... }` **↝**  `{ ... }` **↝** `super(columns);` ?

Comment: @Flatron  don't get it. `AbstractTableModel` only has a no-arg constructor so nothing special here.

Comment: okay sorry I meant that the constructor content should be `super(columns)`;

Comment: @Flatron no, the constructor content should be whatever is needed to actually implement the custom table model, i.e. you'd probably store the column definitions and access them in `getColumnName(int)`, `getColumnClass(int)` etc.

Comment: I am not sure how this is meant exactly, don't I have to pass them to the superclasses constructor? Else if I had some variables within my `CustomTableModel` I would just store them in there but the actual model would still not have them assigned?

Comment: Or better said, if I get passed over into my `CustomTableModel` Class the `ColumnDefinitions` how do I "implement" them into the TableModel itself?

Comment: @Flatron you implement that in your custom table model, `TableModel` is just an interface. Have a look at the methods in `TableModel` which mostly are those you need to implement/overwrite (e.g. there's already a basic default implementation of `getColumnName(int)` in `AbstractTableModel`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104307/discussion-between-flatron-and-thomas).

Comment: `TableModel` provides a `getColumnName` method which, when the `TableModel` is applied to the `JTable`, it uses this information to construct the `TableColumnModel`